# Regular expression replacement HTML tag

Tags: regex, regex-negation

```
<td width="16%" height="123" class="adult_normal_text">
```

`<td height="123" width="86%" colspan="2" class="adult_normal_subheader">`

```
<td width="54%" height="123" >
```

I have three kinds of format < td>,

I want to get rid of "height=123",

And if the presence of class in class behind writing tbdh123

If there is no class add class= "tbdh123".

Thanks

Comment: So you're replacing an explicit height with a class named for an explicit element and height? I'm not entirely convinced it's a huge semantic improvement, although at least it's localized to the stylesheet.

Comment: In what language do you want to to this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#1732454

Comment: use 2 regular expressions to achieve？

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a RegEx. Use an HTML parser. Since I don't know what language you're using, I can't provide a suggestion but it's trivial with one as you can go through your elements and modify attributes easily.

Also see: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#1732454)

Comment: I think in Dreamweaver batch replace